# E-reciept Email scam

Tags: scams

I received an email from Jolene saying that I owe $419, then I looked under my transactions and it said “Deposit Id Number : $417.72, but I don’t ever remember buying that much of a subscription……what could this mean? Is my bank account hacked or is it an actual scam meant to scare me?[image]

[image]

Comment: While knowing your name doesn't mean it is legit (as they can get your name from a lot of places), NOT knowing your name and just calling you "dear subscriber" in an invoice (which legally requires a name in probably every country) is a sure giveaway of spam.

Comment: And a legitimate business sending an email to a customer about a transaction that was unique to that customer would typically put that customer's email address in the primary "To" field.  The fact that this email was sent to "undisclosed-recipients" and a very generic "Dear User" almost certainly means that it was spammed out to hundreds or thousands of email accounts simultaneously.

Comment: It's thoroughly cheeky of them to have used $419 as the amount.

Comment: @Sneftel - there are 'cheeky' things in phishing/scam messages which are intended as filters. Dear Customer (etc), deliberately bad grammar, odd name or name format (e.g. surname-first name) mention of a West African country (Nigeria is the favourite, but I've seen Ghana too), and, as you note, the figures '419'. If the person sees a number of these and still responds, well, putting it kindly, there's a good chance of taking money from them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've heard that reasoning before, and I don't buy it. Scammers know their success rate is going to be low; that's okay, because their time isn't worth much and they cast such a wide net. I suspect any scammer would happily take 100 didn't-pan-out prospects to send an unproductive email to, over giving up a single successful prospect.

Answer (score 14):

This is a "[phishing scam](https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/how-recognize-and-avoid-phishing-scams)". They're sending you some bogus invoice which you'll then contact them about and they'll get the information they want from you.

If you have an actual transaction in your bank account that you don't recognize - contact your bank immediately. Use the contact information you can verify is from the bank, **not** the phone number in the email. For example - call the number on the bank's official website which you always use, or the number on the back of your bank card.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unsure about its legitimacy, take cautious steps to investigate. Check the email source for authenticity, review your bank statements to verify any similar charges, and I wouldn't call any numbers from this email because that could be a scammer's number. Avoid clicking on suspicious links or attachments and consider enhancing your account security by changing passwords and enabling two-factor authentication. If you suspect unauthorized activity, report it immediately to your bank. Most importantly do not click on anything (images/link) from this email.